# Why does display:table set the parent element's height to its biggest floating child element's height?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

For example, I have this these lines of codes:

```
<div class = "parent">
    <div class = "child1">Hello</div>
    <div class = "child2">This child element has the biggest height</div>
    <div class = "child3">Just another ordinary class</div>
</div>
```

And I have the following css:

```
.parent {
    display: table;
}

.child1, .child2, .child3 {
    float: left;
}

.child1 {height: 200px}
.child2 {height: 1000px}
.child3 {height: 500px}
```

Why does it set the parent element height to the same height as "child2"? And why not when the parent element is considered as a block element (since div is displayed as block, right?)?

Also, is it acceptable to use this display:table to set a **non-specified** parent element's **height** to automatically adjust to the height of its biggest floating child element? I've read that we should avoid the use of tables unless the content truly is a table.

Comment: _“Why does it set the parent element height to the same height as child2?”_ - because dat be what tables do …? _“Also, is it acceptable to use this display:table this way?”_ - depends mainly on what you are trying to achieve here (which you failed to mention completely.) _“I've read that we should avoid the use of tables unless the content truly is a table.”_ - go read again, pretty likely that was in regard to using table _elements_ in the HTML for non-tabular data, purely for optical purposes. _Formatting_ stuff to look like a table is something completely different.

Comment: @CBroe _go read again, pretty likely that was in regard to using table elements in the HTML for non-tabular data_ Ah yes. Sorry, I assumed that this was true for CSS too. _depends mainly on what you are trying to achieve here (which you failed to mention completely.)_ Edited, thanks for pointing it out. I apologise for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things going on. When you put non-table elements inside an element with `display:table`, the non-table elements are automatically wrapped in [anonymous objects](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) for table-row and table-cell. So what the layout tree sees is

```
table
  - table-row
      - table-cell
          - child1
          - child2
          - child3
```

Then, all table-cells establish [block formatting contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting), which means that they [contain their floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#root-height), much like using `overflow:hidden` on a block element without a fixed height works as sort of clearfix.

So the table-cell wholly contains the floats, the table-row contains the table-cell and the table contains the table-row. Meaning that the table will be the height of the largest float.

And yes, it's fine to use `display:table` like this. Just don't use real HTML tables for non-tabular data.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Exactly what I was looking for. I have upvoted your answer, but I still have below 15 reputation. Thanks once again!

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn't know about that. I've accepted your answer! @Alohci